# Forçar formato numérico/língua para o documento

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Onde trabalho é muito comum termos problemas com as macros de excel, que geram tabelas e gráficos, dependendo da língua e da versão do Excel que o cliente está usando.

Como forçar uma língua (por exemplo inglês) e consequentes formatos numéricos?
Dessa forma uma trinta porcento apareceria, por exemplo, sempre como **30.00%** e um milhar sempre como **1,000.00** independente da língua do usuário?

PS.: Sei que é possível usar `.NumberFormat` em cada célula, mas estou procurando por uma configuração global que resolva todos os números dentro do documento.

Comment: Pergunta totalmente válida. Até hoje não encontrei como normalizar a localização de arquivos gerados via código.

Comment: @gmsantos creio que com a resposta abaixo fica ok! Creio que quando o mathiasfk testar irá colocar marcar como respondida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quiser utilizar a o ponto ao invés da vírgula em todo os campos da planilha poderá acessar o menu **EXCEL > OPÇÕES > AVANÇADO > 'Usar separador de sistema'** e definir o que deseja.

Para fazer isso via código no VBA utilize a seguinte função:

```
Function setSeparadorDecimal()
  With Application
    .DecimalSeparator = "."
    .ThousandsSeparator = ","
    .UseSystemSeparators = False
  End With 
End Function
```

Conforme advertido pelo nosso amigo @mathiasfk, a função acima altera a **Aplicação** e não somente o arquivo ativo, portanto, caso seja interessante retornar o separador decimal do Excel para o padrão, utilize a função abaixo:

```
Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado! No caso penso que iria resolver apenas para essa cópia do Excel, no caso, a da minha máquina. O meu grande problema é que cada cliente pode ter uma configuração diferente.

Comment: @mathiasfk editei a resposta e creio assim conseguirá forçar o arquivo a utilizar o separador que deseja. Caso esteja correta a resposta, marque como resolvido. Abs!

Comment: Perfeito! Exatamente o que eu procurava.

Comment: Um aviso à quem for usar isso: Essa configuração fica salva no Excel mesmo após o arquivo ser fechado, então é uma boa prática voltar à configuração original no final da sua macro. `Application.UseSystemSeparators = True`